# Share Folders in Peer to Peer Network

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, networking

I Have a Peer to Peer Network with 6 Computers. In Some Computers Windows 7 And In other Install Windows xp.
I shared Some folders in Some Computers.When I want go to other Computer with "\ComputerName" , System Request a Username And Password.How Can I Solve this Problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It also helps to have the same username and password information on all computers. When you connect to a share on another computer in a peer to peer network, windows first checks to see if there is the same credentials on the pc you are trying to connect to, If not, you will get the username / password screen. If you don't like all of the computer accounts showing on the welcome screen you can hide them using the registry. Look on the elder geeks website, http://www.theeldergeek.com/create_hidden_user_account.htm  he would have a lot of info concerning this!!!

Danbo

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an access restriction.  On the computers you shared folders, make sure the permissions are set so that everyone, including Guests, are allowed at very least read access, or read/write if that's what you need.